# AndroidViewClient dump animated view

Tags: android, automated-tests, androidviewclient

One of the view is constantly refreshing (a SeekBar for music progress)

When I try to make a dump, I got this error:
*RuntimeError: The views are being refreshed too frequently to dump.*

Is it possible to freeze the app while the dump is not finished, or something similar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a *uiautomator* limitation. You may try using *ViewServer* as the backend as it works in most cases, however you would need a rooted device or access to the application source code as described in https://github.com/dtmilano/AndroidViewClient/wiki#select-the-correct-implementation.

Comment: I have chosen to use a Broadcast Intent sent via adb shell that pauses the music. It is fire just before any dump.