# the dump problem of AndroidViewClient: The views are being refreshed too frequently to dump

Tags: android, dump, android-uiautomator, androidviewclient

I need to use AndroidViewClient to do some automated testing.
In my code, I use `dump()` of the ViewClient. But I usually meet the following mistake:

> **RuntimeError: The views are being refreshed too frequently to dump.**

It may raise by this:

> **ERROR: could not get idle state.**

dtmilano (the author of Android Application Testing Guide) [answered a similar problem in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27384597/androidviewclient-dump-animated-view). He said there is a uiautomator limitation.

But my API's number is 19, Why there is still a uiautomator limitation? And how can I deal with this problem? How to use `waitforidle()`?

Comment: https://github.com/dtmilano/AndroidViewClient/issues/141

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a [UiAutomator](http://developer.android.com/tools/testing-support-library/index.html#UIAutomator) limitation.

As I mentioned in the other answer, an alternative is to use system *[ViewServe](https://github.com/dtmilano/AndroidViewClient/wiki/System-ViewServer)r* as the backend if your device has **[secure mode](https://github.com/dtmilano/AndroidViewClient/wiki/Secure-mode)** disabled or **[LocalViewServer](https://github.com/dtmilano/AndroidViewClient/wiki/Localviewserver)** if your device is in secure mode but you have access to the source code of the application under test.

### EDIT

`ViewCliet` copes with the differences in the aforementioned backends. That is the same script could run unchanged using a different back end.

For example, to *force* `dump` to use `ViseServer` just run

```
$ dump --force-view-server-use --all
```

You can do the same in your scripts.

Comment: How can I use ViewServer in my python script?  And I need to test lots of apps on Android emulator. I use `viewclient.dump()` by `from com.dtmilano.android.viewclient import ViewClient` and `from com.dtmilano.android.adb.adbclient import AdbClient`. I can't find "ViewServer" in the moudle. I just started learning python and Android auto test, thank you for your help.

Comment: I need to write a heuristic algorithm to test apps. I used `$ dump --force-view-server-use --all` to write into file, and then read it. But now I want to use `list_edittext=vc.dump(window=-1)` in my python.py. Do you mean I need call shell script `$ dump --force-view-server-use --all` in my python.py?

Comment: `dump` was just an example. You can do exactly the same `dump` does from your script. Just take a look at `dump` source code or, even better, use `culebra --force-view-server-use` to generate a script that you can later edit.